# How to detect if a point lies inside a building?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, intersection, google-maps-api

My main motive is to detect if there's in any infrastructure nearby to a given point in a certain radius. For this I am using Places api and using nearbySearch method of it. The problem in this is that it only detects any infrastructure that is already marked by someone on Google Map's.
Eg: http://web.iiit.ac.in/~jayesh.lahori/map.png , blue point is itself inside the building, this will not be detected because nothing has been marked at this spot.

Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't solve this problem in general. Fundamentally, if you don't have the location (with boundary) of every infrastructure location you care about, you cannot tell if any given point lies inside an infrastructure location or not.

You may be able to solve this for a very small area (e.g. by taking an open data source such as [openstreetmap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/12.97770/77.59225) and personally mapping every building boundary that is missing), but there is no way to solve it for the whole world, since buildings come and go all the time.